# Error using GDAL to access HDF5 Bands

Tags: c++, gis, hdf5, gdal

I'm trying to open an HDF5 file, specific bands, but GDAL is giving an error message:

> "'HDF5:C:\pathToFile\pathToFile/filename.h5://ImageData/B4' does not
>   exist in the file system and is not recognised as a supported data set
>   name"

I got the error message after the GDALOpenInternal call using CPLGetLastErrorMsg().  I can't step into GDALOpenInternal (with Visual Studio) because we don't have GDAL source cpp file; just h file that came with the package, unless I'm searching for the wrong file name.

The string for the ConnectionString parameter for GDALOpenInternal is shown in the quotes above.

I found [file does not exist in file system](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112584/qgis-polygonize-error-4-file-does-not-exist-in-the-file-system), but they said it was because of using non-ascii characters in file path string.  I didn't see any other pertinent info on this error message.

We need to access the specific band of the HDF5 file.  I noticed that our slashes in the path are showing in different directions, but I'm not sure that would be the issue here.  We have both windows and linux OS's.  This error was seen on windows os.

We used (gdalinfo.exe filename.HDF5) and do see that the B4 exists there.

Comment: Is 'HDF5:C:\pathToFile\pathToFile/filename.h5://ImageData/B4' the exact path you are trying to open? It looks like pathToFile is there twice and the forward slash before filename.h5 should probably be a backslash on windows.

Comment: I thought of that, but it worked the same with the /'s different directions.  I tried both and it doesn't find the bands.  When I do gdalinfo.exe on the bands, it was showing the quotes like this, so next time I work on it in Visual Studio I'm going to edit the string to have "'s like that and see if it works.  =HDF5:"C:\pathToFile\filename.h5"://ImageData/B2

Comment: I was reading somewhere that windows isn't sensitive to \ directions like linux is.  Maybe gdal is sensitive to that, but it didn't seem to make a difference in the output/error.

Comment: Using the string, HDF5:"C:\pathToFile\filename.h5"://ImageData/B2, didn't work for openInternal with GDAL, FYI.

Comment: I tried fixing my /'s to match what is returned for gdalinfo and it didn't work.  The ConnectionString is now created as follows:  "HDF5:\"" + "c:\pathToFile\pathToFile + String("\\directory\\FILENAME.h5") + String("\"://ImageData/B4");  The error message is the same still.

Comment: I've been looking at the gdal c++ library and I'm not convinced that we can open a file/band in one single step. From the [gdal api tutorial](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html), it looks like you first have to open the file using (pseudocode) 'poDataset = GDALOpen(filepath)', where filepath is "c:\the\path\to\your\file.h5" and then separately loading your band with 'poBand = poDataset->GetRasterBand( yourband )'. Then to see the data in your band you would read it with RasterIO.

Comment: I saw that too (http://gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html), but it seems that it's supposed to work with GDALOpenInternal also according to my co-workers.  We just don't have a good example of the connection string to get it working with GDALOpenInternal since we don't have access to that part of the code that does it.  They want me to focus on using GDALOpenInternal.

Comment: I'm seeing https://lists.alioth.debian.org/pipermail/pkg-grass-devel/2012-November/013971.html, which gives me hope, but doesn't have a good example.  I saw this which could be an example, although it isn't using a path, but I'm not sure: gdalwarp HDF4_SDS:ASTER_L1B:"pg-PR1B0000-2002031402_100_001":2 pg-PR1B0000-2002031402_100_001_2.tif